# Checkboxes tag spring mvc and binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, tags

I have checkboxes tag in my web application with spring mvc. Checkboxes are created from a map in controller like this:

Map demOrgs = createMap();
model.addAttribute("demOrgs", demOrgs); // example : (1, my-description)

1 --> will be value of checkbox
my-description --> will be label of checkbox

In my jsp :

```
<form:form commandName="myBean" method="POST"  >
   <form:checkboxes items="${demOrgs}"  path="demOrg" element='div class="checkboxes"' />
</form:form>
```

My bean has only one field :

String demOrg;

When I send the form demOrg attribute has the value of checkboxes clicked, for example: (1,5,8)

I store myBean in session, when I go to the next step in my application. But when I return, I want the checkboxes were checked, still checked and isn't that way.

When the bind value of checkbox is a boolean value, allways work but I'm binding a custom value :

```
<input id="demOrg1" type="checkbox" value="2" name="demOrg">
<label for="demOrg1">My label description</label>
<input id="demOrg2" type="checkbox" value="3" name="demOrg">
<label for="demOrg2">My label description 2</label>
```

.....

Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1):

What does the signature of your controller method look like? Are you including myBean as a method signature argument, annotated with @ModelAttribute ?

Something like:

```
@RequestMapping(......)
public String myController (@ModelAttribute MyBeanType myBean, Model model) {

    Map demOrgs = createMap();
    model.addAttribute("demOrgs", demOrgs);

    model.addAttribute(myBean);
}
```

Optionally you can annotate the method parameter with @Valid as well if you are using JSR-303 bean validation .

Comment: Yes, my attribute is annotated with @ModelAttribute. When I have a few time I'll try to change String attribute to some collection object..

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to make sure your demOrg property is actually a collection. Check out the
[checkbox reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-checkboxestag) here. In particular, the text that says:

> Typically the bound property is a collection so it can hold multiple values selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Though "myBean" is stored in the session, isn't it reloaded again from the database when the controller is ran?